# Mvc routing in for multiple controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i have two routes in my global file. the route for the propertydetails is working fine but it doesn't works for the booking My links used are. Any idea why its not working

```
      @Html.ActionLinkWithSpan("BookNow", "Create", "Booking", new {item.ProductId,item.ProductName},"gradient-button")

      @Html.ActionLinkWithSpan("MoreDetails", "Index", "PropertyDetails", new        {item.ProductId,item.ProductName},"") 
 routes.MapRoute(
                   "Booking",
                   "Book/{ProductId}/{ProductName}",
                    new { controller = "BookingController", action = "Create", ProductName = UrlParameter.Optional }
               );

        routes.MapRoute(
                    "PropertyDetails",
                    "Details/{ProductId}/{ProductName}",
                     new { controller = "PropertyDetails", action = "Index", ProductName = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it ... just replaced

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Booking",
            url: "{controller}/{ProductId}/{ProductName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "BookingController", action = "Create", ProductId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```